# Indexing string literals for c++ project

Tags: c++, clang, ctags, cscope

I have a huge c++ project and I find myself rgrep-ing for patterns that I know are in string literals. Is there a way to get clang or *x*tags or cscope or whatever to build a file with a mapping of each string literal in the project to the file and line where it was found?

Comment: In general, a good habit could be to give a *name* to your (string) literals and refer to them in the code. Doing so, you could group literal definitions in any way you would like.

Comment: It's not actually my code, it's a legacy project that I have to debug from time to time based on the messages it emits to stderr.

Comment: If this is the case... I'm with you, brother ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to make cscope or friends to do this. You could almost certainly write a custom Starscope extractor that would do this, if you don't mind writing a dozen or so lines of Ruby (starscope: https://github.com/eapache/starscope, adding an extractor: https://github.com/eapache/starscope/blob/master/doc/LANGUAGE_SUPPORT.md#how-to-add-another-language)

Alternatively it may just be enough to use something like `ag` instead, which is grep-like but generally a lot faster: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher